# How can I update Guake in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, update-manager, guake

I am using `guake` version 3.0.5 on Ubuntu 18.04, but I see there are releases up to 3.8.1: https://github.com/Guake/guake/releases.

The Software Center in Ubuntu shows no updates are available.

How can I update `guake` to the latest release?

I have found this to be a problem in general, i.e. I can see a new version is available but I don't know how to apply it. Uninstall and re-install? I tried `sudo apt update`, but it didn't do anything, and I have little clue what I'm doing.

Comment: Related: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general your question is about repositories. Official Ubuntu 18.04 LTS repository provides [Guake 3.0.5](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/guake). With the state of this Ubuntu release you can not get newer version from official repositories.

So you need to find some third-party repository by using applications like [Y PPA Manager](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/y-ppa-manager-easily-search-add-remove.html).
This will end with the following simplest way – install Guake 3.8.1 by adding special [“Linux Uprising” team — Guake PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elinuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/guake?field.series_filter=bionic) for it by using commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/guake
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install guake
```

and then launch Guake.

Reverting to default Guake version will be possible by

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:linuxuprising/guake
```

Comment: fantastic, thank you. I had to restart before seeing the changes, but it's working well

Comment: Great, so you can accept my answer by clicking on check-mark at the left of it. Package of Guake got update, so `pip3 install …` is no longer needed. Thanks [to Logix](https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/1962#issuecomment-975373087).